# Time Machine Restore Woes (how can I edit my backup)

Tags: time-machine, command-line

I have a 2019 MacBook Pro I had to send in for service, as usual it was wiped when I got it back, not an issue as J always have an external drive plugged in for backing up.

This time though my backup won’t work. Whenever I try to restore it runs up to 34 hours before eventually telling me that “An error occurred while restoring from the backup”.

I also tried in Migration Assistant but it just keeps bumping me back to the starting screen. So how do I get back up and running? Is there another way I can time machine my way to success here?

I did find this article while looking at this website:
https://www.harryfear.co.uk/blog/time-machine-error-while-restoring-from-backup
But it seems to be out of date as when I try this method it can’t seems to find TMSafetyNet.kext/Contents/Helpers/bypass
I get the error “No such file or directory”

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Just wondering, have you actually installed macOS onto your MBP? And, if you have, can you manually access your Time Machine files or not?

Comment: Thank you, after I was unsuccessful at the restore I did just do a blank install to try to access time machine and dump out the file that seems to be causing the issue. Something in my Adobe Support folder. But backups are locked down. This is why I was attempting to solve the issue using the instructions in the article above, but Maybe they moved the bypass feature... or I could be typing in the command wrong...

Comment: Can you please add the command you've used (the one which yielded the error) by copy/pasting it directly from Terminal?

Comment: Also, `bypass`  seems to be in `/System/Library/Extensions/TMSafetyNet.kext/Contents/Helpers/bypass` on Mojave.

Comment: Bens-MacBook-Pro:~ BenJamIn$ /System/Library/Extensions/TMSafetyNet.kext/Contents/Helpers/bypass rm -rfv/Volumes/Alternate\ 1985/Backups.backupdb/MacBook\ Pro/2019-09-20-172336/Macintosh\ HD/Library/Application Support/Adobe
-bash: /System/Library/Extensions/TMSafetyNet.kext/Contents/Helper/bypass: No such file or directory

Comment: Bens-MacBook-Pro:~ root# sudo System/Library/Extensions/TMSafetyNet.kext/Contents/Helpers/bypass rm -rfv/Volumes/Alternate\ 1985/Backups.backupdb/MacBook\ Pro/2019-09-20-172336/Macintosh\ HD/Library/Application Support/Adobe
Password:
sudo: System/Library/Extensions/TMSafetyNet.kext/Contents/Helpers/bypass: command not found

Comment: I am copying it over from terminal to note pad and then airdropping it to myself so it looks a little weird